# When we run an executable, do all the sections get loaded into memory at once?

Tags: linux, assembly, process, elf, virtual-memory

So an executable contains of different sections and headers.

At the `ELF Header` we can see some metadata about them like the size of different headers, Starting point etc.

Are the different parts of an executable get loaded into memory all at once?

If yes, **how / when** it is defined and where we can see the information about that because the `ELF Header` doesn't seem to have any parameter in that matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally they are mapped in memory, so you could say that they are lazily loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ELF binaries, sections are not what decides how the binary is loaded into memory.  They are just useful metadata for debuggers and other tools and there doesn't need to be a correspondence between segments and sections and often multiple sections are subsumed under one segment.  A binary can have no section header at all and still load fine.

What actually decides what is getting loaded and where are the *program headers.*  Each program header describes one *memory segment* and contains the following information:

- the field `p_type` tells you what kind of information the program header contains.  This is typically just `PT_LOAD` to mean “loadable segment.”
- the field `p_offset` tells you the offset from the beginning of the file where the segment resides.  Note that in rare cases, this can lie beyond the end of the file.
- the field `p_vaddr` tells you the virtual address at which the segment is mapped.  There is also `p_paddr` to specify a physical address, but it's generally unused.
- the field `p_filesz` tells you how long the segment is in the file.
- the field `p_memsz` tells you how long the segment is in memory.  If this is more than the segment length in the file, the remainder is filled with zeroes.
- the field `p_flags` tells you if the segment is readable (`PF_R`), writable (`PF_W`), executable (`PF_X`) or some combination of these three.  When loading a segment, the operating system uses these flags to set up write and executable protection.
- the field `p_align` tells you how the segment is aligned.  This is not really important here.

When the operating system loads your binary or when the runtime link editor loads a shared object, it reads the program headers of your binary and loads or maps each segment in the order they appear.  Once this is done, your program is executed.

You can get information about the program headers of a binary by running `readelf -l binary`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.